# A word that means "interesting-ness"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to make a sentence about evaluating how interesting something is. I'm evaluating its ________?

Comment: interestingness.

Comment: Huh, that actually is a word...

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Interestingness http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interesting

Comment: mystique, draw, attractiveness

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *interest* itself can be used.

I'm evaluating its *interest*.

Answer (score 2):

*Allure* and *charm* do have some ***appeal***.

Answer (score 1):

As @ermanen suggested, interestingness is a word; I then used it to find synonyms. I found "allure" and "charm" to be better fits!